# internet unreachable on 22.04 post adding static ip configuration

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, virtualbox, internet

I boot up a new virtual box ubuntu server instance - 22.04.3 lts from its iso image.

At this point I am able to run commands such as `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, etc and they run as expected.

Then I shutdown the vm, and, open its settings, add a second network adapter - host-only adapter. The pics below will describe the adapter configuration:

[image]

Then I boot into the vm and edit the `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` as follows:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.118.10/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [61.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.118.1
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

Then I run `sudo netplan apply`. The command succeeds.

Now I can connect to the vm via the static ip address, however, the internet is unreachable.

A simple curl command now timesout when trying to connect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

---

#### Issue Resolved

Turns out all I needed in the interface config for `enp0s8` was `dhcp4` and `addresses`. After making this change, and doing `netplan apply` internet was reachable.

Still have no clue why this works, and, the old configuration fails.

Comment: Host-only adapters don't have Internet access, they're private to the virtualization infrastructure and the host machine.  Unless your host system is configured with proper NAT rules, then you need to actually use a NAT'd connection link or a Bridged connection, not a Host-only one unless you have a firewall or NAT system in place to handle routing that traffic.

Comment: There is a NAT system. The initial commands like `sudo apt update` etc were successful because of them. Other non-ubuntu VMs work in a manner similar to the above. If I remove the `enp0s8` configuration entirely and reboot the machine, my internet begins to work as usual.